# Garage door bottom retainer fell off

Tags: doors, garage

Our SUV backed out before the door completely opened and the SUV's fin antenna knocked this retainer off.

I am unable to force it back into place while bending one side of the track with a flathead screw driver - unless there is a special technique.

Given the construction it looks like it slides into the bottom track before the panel was connected. There are no screws.

What are my options to fixing this problem? Ideally I would like to reattach this piece but I've never removed a panel before. Is there a special technique to reattach it?

Here are some helpful photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That "retainer" is more correctly called a sweep. It provides a partial weather seal at the bottom of the door, when the door is closed. It's a replaceable part, because sweeps do eventually wear out. Unfortunately, I can't advise you on the details of exactly how this one clips to the door, but it's probably straightforward.

Comment: It's not really a sweep unless it sweeps. Overhead doors don't. :) It's a _gasket_, to my mind, or just a seal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try again to squeeze it in place from below.

1. Have a friend support it at the center to hold position, or hang it with tape. You'll want it slightly low so you approach the door panel at an angle.
2. Using a wide-jaw pliers like a Channellock, squeeze the very end to get it started. You could also use a woodworking clamp or similar, but you may need spacers to apply the force near the top flange and not at the bottom bend. Hold it in position or use more tape to do so.
3. Move a short distance and squeeze again. Your helper should raise the rail as needed to work it in as you go along. Be careful to not over-compress it and destroy the tension. A bit of lube might help.

If that doesn't work, you would have to release the door spring to swing the panel out. That's a fairly big job and carries a degree of danger with it. You'd pull those red screws (red means danger) after removing tension. The problem is that the door will be very heavy at this point. Plan A is your best bet.

---

Actually, this is probably installed at the factory from the bottom, not the end. A simple roller mechanism would compress it and press it in place.

Comment: IIUC, you're suggesting squeezing the door in order to slide the trim piece on the bottom?

Comment: No. The strip in hand is a spring. Squeeze the spring.

Comment: Ah, you're suggesting that the shiny metal of the flange goes between the exterior steel and the interior wood core. Gotcha. Glad I asked.

Comment: No. There's no wood core in a door like this. It rests between the two beads shaped into the bottom of the panel.

Comment: The bottom two pics appear to show a wood-like core. There's got to be something solid in there to hold the inner & outer skins together beyond just this metal piece, otherwise, they'd just be flapping in the breeze right now. Maybe I should just go take a nap...

Comment: No. Modern overhead doors are either all steel or steel with foam inside. No wood. That's texture molded into the sheet steel, which wraps completely around.

Comment: Think of the shape profile of a soda can bottom. Same thing, but with a little more depression up in the corner to catch the spring strip.

Comment: The OP might benefit from prying the edges of the metal channel apart slightly before reinstalling, to ensure that it fully seats in the bead(s).

Comment: Well, not if it's _already_ a difficult task to reinstall it.

Comment: I was able to refix the retainer back in place. Since I was alone I disconnected the chain and rested the door on my shoulder a ladder. After inserting one side of the rail in, about 12 inches, I dropped the door on my shoulder (I was on my knees) to keep the rail firmly in place. Then I used a large flat-head to force the other side in. By now I had a good idea of the tension in the material and applied force accordingly. I moved back clipping 6 inches at a time repeating the same. After the half way point, I used a mallet and flathead to complete it.

Comment: The wood clamp and channel-locks were good ideas but interfered due to the construction of the rail and proximity to the door panel lip. However, they helped me get a good idea of the elasticity / tension of the material to device a plan. Essentially I followed your idea but used the tools and techniques available to me to achieve the same result. Thanks.